# Deriving sphere surface integrating over circumferences of cross-sections

Tags: calculus, integration

This seems so simple, yet something is so wrong. I am merely trying to derive the surface area of a sphere by summing up all of the little circumferences of the cross-sectional circles as I move along the x-axis from $-r$ to $r$.

This is my integral:

$$\int_{-r}^{r} 2\pi \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \,dx $$

Just moving along the x-axis and adding up $2\pi*[radius\ at\ that\ x]$. And the radius of the cross-section at each $x$ is $\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

That integral gives me $(\pi r)^2$, which is not quite $4\pi r^2$.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to stick flat rings(circumference x dx)  on a circle, but you need to have curved rings.

You can adjust for this by multiplying by $\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}$, where $f(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$.

Refer to the arc-length integral.

Comment: i'm not sure how to explain my first sentence but

Comment: https://www.askamathematician.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/tumblr_lbxrvcK4pk1qbylvso1_400.png

Comment: I don’t understand: isn’t the circumference of the cross-section at each x like the arc length, and I’m just adding up all the infinitely thin arc lengths?

Comment: can you try to make an integral to compute** the circumference of a circle?

Comment: if you $\int_0^2 1\,dx + \int_0^2 1 dx$, you'll get a perimeter of $4$, which is clearly wrong

Comment: Sorry I'm a little lost. Why would I have those two integrals? The integral of the circumference of a circle is its area, but I don't see how that's related.

Comment: an integral to find the circumference, is what i meant

Comment: the problem is that your slices are not approaching the surface in a smooth way

Comment: did you see the link i attached

Comment: Where is the jaggedness coming from? If I have a curve $y=the\ circumference\ at\ each\ x$, wouldn't it be continuous?

Comment: think of thin rectangular slices. they are jagged in the same way

Comment: If each skinny rectangle is the integrand at an x *dx, don't the rectangles grow and shrink continuously? i.e. together, aren't they smooth?

Comment: see, yeah, that's a misconception. that only works on a flat plane. here, you're working on a sphere

Comment: on a flat plane, you're still multiplying by $\sqrt{1+f'(x,y)^2}$, however in this case, it's flat so f(x,y)=0 and you don't deal with that term

Comment: It's not quite clicking yet. I'll sleep on it and check back in after.

Comment: i think you might want to read about it. i didn't understand until i actually read about arc length formula